# Is $r^2-4r\cos(\theta)=14$ an equation of a circle or cylinder?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, surfaces

A question asks to identify the surface of the polar equation
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
r^2-4r\cos(\theta)=14.
\end{equation}
I converted $(1)$ into Cartesian coordinates: 
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
(x-2)^2+y^2 = (3\sqrt{2})^2.
\end{equation}
I would have thought $(2)$ represents the equation of a cylinder, because the question asks to identify a surface.

Comment: in how many dimensions?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^2$ it's a circle.  In $\mathbb{R}^3$ it's a cylinder (using *cylindrical coordinates* $(x,y,z)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,z)$).

Comment: @BarryCipra Okay. So is the answer dependent on the context of the question?

Comment: @Gurjinder, yes, exactly.

Comment: @BarryCipra Cool, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is of course a circle. General formula for the circle is $$(x-p)^2+(y-q)^2 =r^2$$

where $O=(p,q)$ is a center and $r$ radius. At your case $O=(2,0)$ and $r=3\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I think we should recognize that this is also the equation of a cylinder whose axis of symmetry is parallel to the $z$ axis

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{equation}\tag{1}
r^2-4r\cos(\theta)=14.
\end{equation}$$
$$x^2+y^2-4x=14$$
$$(x-2)^2+y^2=18$$
$$(x-2)^2+y^2=(3\sqrt{2})^2$$